# Add a thread with Queue Waiting

Tags: java, queue, threadpool

I have an application that uses a single file as a read input, I'd use a queue to acess this file,

I'd like to implement a singleton threadpool, with waiting queue but I do not know how,

The queue must contain the http request of all client request,

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to implement a threadpool singleton with wainting queue in java

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()). Note that the queue it uses is unbounded.